# Return level in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compute return levels for a certain return period (20 years) for my extreme precipitation. Using the block maxima approach, I made the following object to extract the maximum values:

```
Gcomb <-c(Gmax[1], Gmax1[1], Gmax2[1], Gmax3[1], Gmax4[1], Gmax5[1], Gmax6[1], Gmax7[1], Gmax8[1], 
Gmax[2], Gmax1[2], Gmax2[2], Gmax3[2], Gmax4[2], Gmax5[2], Gmax6[2], Gmax7[2], Gmax8[2], Gmax[3], 
Gmax1[3], Gmax2[3], Gmax3[3], Gmax4[3], Gmax5[3], Gmax6[3], Gmax7[3], Gmax8[3], Gmax[4], Gmax1[4], 
Gmax2[4], Gmax3[4], Gmax4[4], Gmax5[4], Gmax6[4], Gmax7[4], Gmax8[4], Gmax[5], Gmax1[5], Gmax2[5], 
Gmax3[5], Gmax4[5], Gmax5[5], Gmax6[5], Gmax7[5], Gmax8[5], Gmax[6], Gmax1[6], Gmax2[6], Gmax3[6], 
Gmax4[6], Gmax5[6], Gmax6[6], Gmax7[6], Gmax8[6], Gmax[7], Gmax1[7], Gmax2[7], Gmax3[7], Gmax4[7], 
Gmax5[7], Gmax6[7], Gmax7[7], Gmax8[7])
```

Gcomb looks like this:

```
>Gcomb

[1] 191.46960 115.77133 209.15147 243.26880  84.97396 157.38678 138.84937 
140.96840 143.80301 196.87990 131.89099
[12] 137.08264 231.11342 116.67323 125.27563 100.72293 159.45056 198.12399 
216.74820 120.16774 147.73828 396.64862
[23] 164.02292 132.94519  99.95055 162.81708 186.59691 219.53568 124.76086 
174.99396 231.20859 108.70350 139.22649
[34] 160.40935 159.03806 162.56891 217.58543 123.11100 149.26378 245.90994  
92.68985 152.45033 171.12381 159.27040
[45] 141.19446 205.46706 101.71022 163.25592 328.31265 119.69154 122.01060 
114.79624 147.92126 179.91318 200.70750
[56] 110.50108 231.30966 213.02881 125.74141 152.19133  98.35700 204.43138 
182.53252
```

Now, when I try to compute the return level (a 20-year return level):

```
library(extRemes)
return.level.fevd(Gcomb, return.period = 20)
```

I end up with the following error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What could be causing this error? I tried creating a vector with the same values, but the error persists

Any help or insight for this would be very appreciated!

Comment: could you specify the package from which `return.level.fevd` comes from?

Comment: DJJ - it is from the package called "extRemes"

Comment: from the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extRemes/extRemes.pdf) . `return.level(x)`  where `x` is  A list object of class “fevd” as returned by fevd. In the case of the print method
function, an object returned by return.level

Comment: DJJ - In this case, "x" would be "Gcomb", as I have above, no? I don't understand why that error keeps appearing, however.

Comment: Gcomb is not a `list` but a `vector`. `class(Gcomb)`.  I advise you to read the manual and do the examples associated with it.   As we used say RTFM because those who WTFM do not want to write it again. ;-). You can execute `? return.level` know more about the function, or `example(return.level) ` to have access to the example. I'm afraid I cannot help more than that because I don't know what `Gcomb` is.

Comment: DJJ - I think I got it to work, thanks!

Comment: Glad you made it. Feel free to answer your question ;-)